# Inserting an element prevents click event from firing

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a simple form validator. When you click away from the input, it displays an error message (when necessary).

However, I have noticed a side effect. When the error message is inserted into the form, it shifts the submit button downward, which prevents the submit event from firing.

Take a look at the snippet below. This overly simplified example emulates the problem. Try clicking on the input and then the button. You'll notice that the button's click event won't fire because it is shifted downwards.

```js
function insert() {   
  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), button);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input onblur="insert()" />
<button onclick="alert()">Click</button>
```

How can I resolve this problem? Keep in mind that for my form validator, the button is of type submit and the event that won't fire is the form's submit event, but the same concept can clearly be applied here.

Comment: Just to clarify, make sure you click on the input *first* and then directly click on the button, before clicking elsewhere. The `alert()` won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `alert()` isn't firing is because the created `div` element is inserted with the `blur` event before the `click` event occurs. Then when the `click` event occurs, it doesn't register with the button because the button is moved on the page. In the example below, I added a `delayInsert` function to demonstrate this.

Steps:

1. Click in the input field
2. Click the `Click` button

The `alert()` will fire before the `div` is inserted.

```js
function delayInsert() {
  setTimeout(insert, 1000);
}

function insert() {
  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), button);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input onblur="delayInsert()" />
<button onclick="alert()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for me. When I edit the txt box, the div is appended. When I click the button, it alerts. Try using js to get the data and send a xmlHTTPrequest to the php?

Comment: Do not edit the input. Click on it, and then click on the button. The `alert()` event won't fire.

Comment: I believe when you are in the text box and click elsewhere, it deselects the textbox instead of fireing an onclick event.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).